# ng-sortable not working when drooping an li to an empty ul?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ng-sortable

I am facing an issue when i drop an li element to a ul which is empty it is unable to drop that li element. It is working fine if ul contain li. Please help me. Thanks in advance

```
<ul>
                    <li class="heading-row">
                        <div class="cell-col cell-1">
                            <strong>Group</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cell-col cell-2">
                            <strong>#</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cell-col cell-3">
                            <strong>Nick Name</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cell-col cell-4">
                            <strong>Company</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cell-col cell-5">
                            <strong>Rating</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cell-col cell-6">
                            <strong>Car Info</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cell-col cell-7">
                            <strong>Car Type</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cell-col cell-8">
                            <strong>Capacity</strong>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <!--ng repeat-->


                    <li id="rowd.id" ng-repeat="rowd in rowData.data">
                        <div>
                            <div class="cell-col cell-1">{{rowd.name}}
                            </div>
                            <div class="cell-col cell-group-2">
                                <div class="cell-item-rw">
                                    <ul class="data card-list ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid driver_data"
                                        as-sortable="waitaddSortOptions" ng-model="rowd.data">
                                        <li class="{{rowq.id}} rowq" data-ng-repeat="rowq in rowd.data"
                                            ng-dblClick="selectedDriver(rowq)" as-sortable-item>
                                            <div as-sortable-item-handle="" class="as-sortable-item-handle">
```

Comment: Can you please provide complete example code, or jsfiddle?

Comment: Above is the complete code.

Comment: I am in great trouble from last couple of hours. please tell me where i am lacking

Comment: What happens when you are trying to drop first li? Is there any error in console?

Comment: No there is no error in console. A placeholder is not built when i drag the li element and put on that empty ul.

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: One thing i just want to clear you that i have multiple ul and each ul contain li. when i drop an li element from one ul to another empty ul its not working, but if that ul contain atleast one li the element is dropped.

Comment: Its on my local server. I am unable to show you working example.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Gurpinder/achtd6tn/1/. Here is the complete code with my json

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/PagFeswvEr64vHd5PCqd?p=preview shows the example of multiple nested sortable elements. it also contains an empty list element on which you can drag items from other list.

Comment: @Gurpinder : in the below li tag <li class="{{rowq.id}} rowq" data-ng-repeat="rowq in rowd.data"  ng-dblClick="selectedDriver(rowq)" as-sortable-item> add style  ng-style="{'min-height': '20px'}". So  ,when there is an empty list it allow to drag element.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the style **ng-style="{'min-height': '20px'}"** to li tag

```
 <li class="{{rowq.id}} rowq" data-ng-repeat="rowq in rowd.data" ng-dblClick="selectedDriver(rowq)" ng-style="{'min-height': '20px'}" as-sortable-item> 

Now you are able to drop element in empty list.
```